# Windows 8 automatic store updates

Tags: windows-8, updates, windows-store

I have used the express settings, so Windows updates should already be enabled, but it seems this doesn't affect the Windows Store updates.

It still wants me to click "Install" in the updates screen. How can I make all updates automatic, including app updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Store app, Charms, Settings, App Updates, and select Yes for 'Automatically download updates for my apps'.

Comment: Ah, missed the charms.

Comment: @cable729 I find that this doesn't actually seem to do anything. Or perhaps it downloads the updates, but doesn't install them automatically?

Comment: Hmm, if this doesn't work then hopefully Microsoft will fix it with the next Store update.